# Clip-path inset circle

Tags: css, geometry, clip-path, vinyl

I have a squared image and want to cut it middle with a circle shape to see what's behind (actually a body background-image).
I found `clip-path` CSS property, but I only arrive to create a circle with the image instead of creating a circle surrounded by my image.

Until now I had a white background, so I just created a `::after` element white, with an inset box-shadow but now I got an image for the background so I can't keep that.

Is there a way with or without clip-path to achieve that?

PS: the final goal is to create a music vinyl rotating, so this middle hole is necessary! :)

Thanks.

Comment: yes it's possible, share some code

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this using `mask` and not `clip-path`

```css
img {
  border-radius:50%;
  -webkit-mask:radial-gradient(farthest-side,transparent 15%,#fff 16%);
          mask:radial-gradient(farthest-side,transparent 15%,#fff 16%);
}

body {
  background:linear-gradient(to right,gray,yellow);
}
```

```html
<img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/1003/400/400.jpg">
```

Comment: why `farthest-side`? I tried with `circle at 50% 50%` and I got the same result.

Comment: @dgknca farthest-side allow me to have better control over the color percentage. 100% with color will be the edge of the element while with `circle at 50% 50%` (which is the same as `circle`) I need to use around 66% which is not trivial: https://jsfiddle.net/7d6mck8o/

Comment: @dgknca relevant part from the specification: https://drafts.csswg.org/css-images-3/#valdef-radial-gradient-ending-shape and a related asnwer with many radial-gradient examples: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57218554/8620333

Comment: thanks for this pretty informative and in depth answer.