# How can I avoid using 'at' in radial-gradient?

Tags: css, radial-gradients

I want to get the result below but without using the `at` syntax because it's not supported in Safari, I'm having a hard time with it. Does any one know any approach? Thank you in advance!

```css
#content {
  background-color: black;
  height: 300px;
  width: 500px;
}

#inverted-circle {
  background: radial-gradient(110% 200% at 50% 0, white 49.9%, rgba(255,255,255,0) 50.05%);
  position: relative;
  content: '';
  height: 220px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
  <div id="inverted-circle"></div>
</div>
```

It's still not working on Safari on iOS

[image: not working on safari]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider `background-size`/`background-position`. You make the background twice bigger in height, you divide the vertical radius by 2 and you place your background at the bottom.

```css
#content {
  background-color: black;
  height: 300px;
  width: 500px;
}

#inverted-circle {
  background: 
    radial-gradient(110% 100%, white 49.9%, transparent 50.05%) 
    bottom/
    100% 200%;
  height: 220px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
  <div id="inverted-circle"></div>
</div>
```

Related to get more details: [How to animate a radial-gradient using CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57218443/8620333)

---

You can also optimize your code with only one element:

```css
#content {
  height: 300px;
  width: 500px;
  background: 
    radial-gradient(55% 36.5%, white 99.5%, black 100%) 
     bottom /
     100% 200%;
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
</div>
```

Comment: I don't know why but is still not working in Iphone on Safari (i have added an image to the post) @temani

Comment: @CalistoQueets did you clear your cache? is it working fine on Desktop Safari?

Comment: Yes do it both and it seems to work on iPad but not on iPhone5s

Comment: @CalistoQueets maybe that version of iPhone is quite old and you also need the prefix version : https://www.zonecss.fr/proprietes-css/webkit-radial-gradient-css-fonction.html