# How to hide a ::before or ::after under the outline?

Tags: css, pseudo-element

I've tried:

- making parent's overflow hidden
- making z-index negative

[on chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tEmok.png)
[on firefox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pGY4z.png)

I've noticed that the issue appears only when the 'outline' is set to 'auto'. 
Any ideas to fix it without messing with browser's default outline?

Thank you.

```css
#switch {
  position: relative;
  background: transparent;
  border: 0;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#switch:focus {
  outline: 5px dotted blue;
  outline-style: auto;
  z-index: 0;
}

#switch .mode {
  position: relative;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #1a202c;
  transition: transform 0.45s ease;
}

#switch .mode::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: -30%;
  left: 30%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: white;
  transition: transform 0.45s ease;
}
```

```html
<button id="switch">
    <div class="mode"></div>
  </button>
```

Comment: Can you add your code?

Comment: Interesting problem, I would like to hear solution ideas. For a hack solution; making moon::after circle's size a little smaller is one of the options you have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try add `overflow: hidden` to #switch .mode and then set it to `visible` in dark

```js
const button = document.getElementById("switch");
const container = document.querySelector(".container");

window.addEventListener("load", () => {
  if (document.window.matchMedia("(prefers-color-scheme: dark)").matches) {
    container.classList.toggle("dark");
  }
});

button.addEventListener("click", () => {
  container.classList.toggle("dark");
});
```

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  margin: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background: white;
}

#switch {
  position: relative;
  background: transparent;
  border: 0;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#switch:focus {
  outline: 5px dotted blue;
  outline-style: auto;
  z-index: 0;
}

#switch .mode {
  position: relative;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background:linear-gradient(to left bottom,white 35%,#1a202c 35%);
  transition: transform 0.45s ease;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#switch .mode::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 6px;
  height: 6px;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: inherit;
  z-index: -1;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: box-shadow 0.4s 0s ease;
}

#switch .mode::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: -30%;
  left: 30%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: white;
  transition: transform 0.45s ease;
}

.container.dark {
  background: #1a202c;
}
.container.dark #switch .mode {
  transform: scale(0.5);
  background: white;
  overflow: visible;
}
.container.dark #switch .mode::before {
  opacity: 1;
  box-shadow: 0 -20px 0 0 white, 0 20px 0 0 white, -20px 0 0 0 white, 20px 0 0 0 white, 15px 15px 0 0 white, 15px -15px 0 0 white, -15px 15px 0 0 white, -15px -15px 0 0 white;
}
.container.dark #switch .mode::after {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translateX(50%) translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="container dark">
  <button id="switch">
    <div class="mode"></div>
  </button>
</div><div class="container dark">
  <button id="switch">
    <div class="mode"></div>
  </button>
</div>
```

Comment: Great! The only thing that worries me is, there is a small border on that circle. Is there an option to hide it somehow?

Comment: Sure, I've just updated my answer, by applying the code above, we're still having a nice animation on transition.

Answer (score 0):

Do it differently using only background instead of pseudo element. You can also have transparency:

```css
#switch {
  background: pink;
  border: 0;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

#switch:focus {
  outline: 5px dotted blue;
  outline-style: auto;
}

#switch .mode {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: 
    radial-gradient(circle 10px,transparent 98%,#1a202c)
    bottom 20% left 20%/ /* adjust this to control the position */
    200% 200%;
  transition: transform 0.45s ease;
}
```

```html
<button id="switch">
    <div class="mode"></div>
  </button>
```

Related to get more details about `radial-gradient`: [How to animate a radial-gradient using CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57218443/8620333)