Radial SVG gradient is not animating on hover
The radial gradient is supposed to grow from 10% to 100% on hover, but it's just not doing anything. Can't understand what I'm doing wrong.


<svg id="svgDoc" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 500 500" shape-rendering="geometricPrecision" text-rendering="geometricPrecision">

<style><![CDATA[
#svgDoc {
    pointer-events: all
}

#svgDoc:hover #svgGrad {
    animation: svgGrad_f_p 3000ms linear 1 normal forwards
}

@keyframes svgGrad_f_p {
    0% {
        offset: 10%
    } 
    100% {
        offset: 100%
    }
}
]]>
</style>

<defs>
<radialGradient id="svgGrad-fill" cx="0" cy="0" r="0.5" spreadMethod="pad" gradientUnits="objectBoundingBox" gradientTransform="translate(0.5 0.5)">
<stop id="svgGrad-fill-0" offset="0%" stop-color="#ff0000"/>
<stop id="svgGrad-fill-1" offset="10%" stop-color="#000"/>
</radialGradient>
</defs>

<rect id="svgGrad" width="500" height="500" rx="0" ry="0" fill="url(#svgGrad-fill)"/>
</svg>




https://stackoverflow.com/q/57218443/8620333

you need to animate the offset of a single gradient.

@RobertLongson I've edited my original code to try to animate the offset. But I suspect I didn't do it right because it's still not working. Oy.

You can't manipulate the stop attribute via CSS as it "collides" with the CSS offset-path related property of the same name.
Workaround 1: SMIL animations triggered by begin attribute
A workaround might be to animate the gradient via SMIL animation like so:


<h3>Hover me</h3>
<svg id="svgDoc" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 500 500">
  <defs>
    <radialGradient id="svgGrad-fill" cx="0" cy="0" r="0.5" spreadMethod="pad" gradientUnits="objectBoundingBox" gradientTransform="translate(0.5 0.5)">
      <stop id="svgGrad-fill-0" offset="0%" stop-color="#ff0000" />
      <stop id="svgGrad-fill-1" offset="10%" stop-color="#000" >
           <animate attributeName="offset" fill="freeze" values="0.1;1" dur="1s" repeatCount="1" begin="svgGrad.mouseover"  /> 
           <animate attributeName="offset" fill="freeze" values="1;0.1" dur="1s" repeatCount="1" begin="svgGrad.mouseout"  /> 
      </stop>
    </radialGradient>
  </defs>

  <rect id="svgGrad" width="500" height="500" rx="0" ry="0" fill="url(#svgGrad-fill)" />
</svg>



Fortunately, SVG's <animate> element allows you to
add events to start (or stop) playback. See "mdn docs: begin"
<animate attributeName="offset" fill="freeze" values="1;0.1" dur="1s" repeatCount="1" begin="svgGrad.mouseout"  /> 

Adding transition easing
We need to calcMode="spline" and keySplines attributes to define a custom easing – similar to CSS easing:

Ease-in: keySplines="0.42 0 1 1"
Ease-in-out: keySplines="0.42 0 0.58 1"
Ease: keySplines="0.25 0.1 0.25 1"

Like the keyTimes attribute we can specify multiple values as an array separated by semicolons.
In your  case we only have 2 animation states (begin:0.1/10% end: 1/100%) as descibed by the keyTimes attribute. Therefore we only need a single bézier value. Otherwise we need to repeat the keySplines according to the keyTimes where keySplines=keyTimes .length-1.
Here's an example comparing the easing results


body{
font-size:3vmin;
display:grid;
grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
gap:1em;
}
<div class="col">
<h3>linear</h3>
<svg viewBox="0 0 500 500">
  <defs>
    <radialGradient id="svgGrad-fill" cx="50%" cy="50%" r="0.5" spreadMethod="pad" gradientUnits="objectBoundingBox">
      <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#ff0000" />
      <stop offset="10%" stop-color="#000">
        
       <animate attributeName="offset" fill="freeze" values="0.1;1;0.1" keyTimes="0;0.5;1"  dur="1s" repeatCount="indefinite" begin="0" />

        <!--
        <animate attributeName="offset" fill="freeze" values="0.1;1" keyTimes="0;1" dur="1s" repeatCount="1" begin="svgGrad.mouseover" />
        <animate attributeName="offset" fill="freeze" values="1;0.1" keyTimes="0;1" dur="1s" repeatCount="1" begin="svgGrad.mouseout" />
-->
      </stop>
    </radialGradient>
  </defs>

  <rect id="svgGrad" width="500" height="500" rx="0" ry="0" fill="url(#svgGrad-fill)" />
</svg>
</div>


<div class="col">
<h3>Ease-in-out</h3>
<svg viewBox="0 0 500 500">
  <defs>
    <radialGradient id="svgGradFillEaseInOut" cx="50%" cy="50%" r="0.5" spreadMethod="pad" gradientUnits="objectBoundingBox">
      <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#ff0000" />
      <stop offset="10%" stop-color="#000">
        
        <animate attributeName="offset" fill="freeze" values="0.1;1;0.1" keyTimes="0;0.5;1" calcMode="spline" keySplines="0.42 0 0.58 1; 0.42 0 0.58 1" dur="1s" repeatCount="indefinite" begin="0" />
        <!--
        <animate attributeName="offset" fill="freeze" values="0.1;1" keyTimes="0;1" calcMode="spline" keySplines="0.42 0 0.58 1" dur="1s" repeatCount="1" begin="svgGradEaseInOut.mouseover" />
        <animate attributeName="offset" fill="freeze" values="1;0.1" keyTimes="0;1" calcMode="spline" keySplines="0.42 0 0.58 1" dur="1s" repeatCount="1" begin="svgGradEaseInOut.mouseout" />
-->
      </stop>
    </radialGradient>
  </defs>
  <rect id="svgGradEaseInOut" width="500" height="500" rx="0" ry="0" fill="url(#svgGradFillEaseInOut)" />
</svg>
</div>


<div class="col">
<h3>Ease-in</h3>
<svg viewBox="0 0 500 500">
  <defs>
    <radialGradient id="svgGradFillEaseIn" cx="50%" cy="50%" r="0.5" spreadMethod="pad" gradientUnits="objectBoundingBox">
      <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#ff0000" />
      <stop offset="10%" stop-color="#000">
        <animate attributeName="offset" fill="freeze" values="0.1;1;0.1" keyTimes="0;0.5;1" calcMode="spline" keySplines="0.42 0 1 1; 0.42 0 1 1" dur="1s" repeatCount="indefinite" begin="0" />

        <!--
        <animate attributeName="offset" fill="freeze" values="0.1;1" keyTimes="0;1" calcMode="spline" keySplines="0.42 0 1 1" dur="1s" repeatCount="1" begin="svgGradEaseIn.mouseover" />
        <animate attributeName="offset" fill="freeze" values="1;0.1" keyTimes="0;1" calcMode="spline" keySplines="0.42 0 1 1" dur="1s" repeatCount="1" begin="svgGradEaseIn.mouseout" />
-->
      </stop>
    </radialGradient>
  </defs>
  <rect id="svgGradEaseIn" width="500" height="500" rx="0" ry="0" fill="url(#svgGradFillEaseIn)" />
</svg>
</div>

<div class="col">
<h3>Ease</h3>
<svg viewBox="0 0 500 500">
  <defs>
    <radialGradient id="svgGradFillEase" cx="50%" cy="50%" r="0.5" spreadMethod="pad" gradientUnits="objectBoundingBox">
      <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#ff0000" />
      <stop offset="10%" stop-color="#000">
        
        <animate attributeName="offset" fill="freeze" values="0.1;1;0.1" keyTimes="0;0.5;1" calcMode="spline" keySplines="0.25 0.1 0.25 1; 0.25 0.1 0.25 1" dur="1s" repeatCount="indefinite" begin="0" />

        
        <!--
        <animate attributeName="offset" fill="freeze" values="0.1;1" keyTimes="0;1" calcMode="spline" keySplines="0.25 0.1 0.25 1" dur="1s" repeatCount="1" begin="svgGradEase.mouseover" />
        <animate attributeName="offset" fill="freeze" values="1;0.1" keyTimes="0;1" calcMode="spline" keySplines="0.25 0.1 0.25 1" dur="1s" repeatCount="1" begin="svgGradEase.mouseout" />
-->
      </stop>
    </radialGradient>
  </defs>
  <rect id="svgGradEase" width="500" height="500" rx="0" ry="0" fill="url(#svgGradFillEase)" />
</svg>
</div>



Workaround 2: CSS custom @property
By defining custom properties for start and end offsets we can also achieve a smooth gradient transition.


@property --offset1 {
  syntax: "<percentage>";
  inherits: false;
  initial-value: 0%;
}


@property --offset2 {
  syntax: "<percentage>";
  inherits: false;
  initial-value: 10%;
}


.gradient{
  background: radial-gradient( #FF0000 var(--offset1), #000 var(--offset2));
  transition:1s --offset1, 1s --offset2;
}

.gradient:hover{
  --offset1: 5%;
  --offset2:100%;
}
<h3>Gradient CSS</h3>
<svg id="svgDoc2" class="gradient" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 500 500">
</svg>



This won't work with CSS variables as we can't transition the background property itself.
In this approach we're applying a CSS gradient to the outermost (parent) SVG element – accepting CSS gradient styles just like a HTML element (unlike inner SVG elements).
However, the SMIL approach probably still offers the best cross-browser compatibility.
See also:

"mdn docs: @property"
"css-tricks: Using @property for CSS Custom Properties"
"CSS-tricks: A Guide to SVG Animations (SMIL)"
Temani Afif's answer:"How to animate a radial-gradient using CSS?"


Thank you! One question: can smooth transition/easing be applied to your first workaround?

@Alan. easing is a bit un-intuitive in SVG SMIL. I added more info to the answer. But you see the gradient transitioned or actually just instantly changing (without a linear transition)?

Thank you for adding the easing. I just found a glitch in the SMIL animation: if you hover and quickly unhover (without waiting for the gradient to fully expand), the mouseout animation doesn't continue from the current position, it starts from 100%. For example, @propety workaround doesn't have this glitch. Is it possible to fix this glitch in SMIL?

Sorry I'm afraid you can't fix it for SMIL. Probably, the CSS approach is the better option for your needs.

Understood. Could I ask you another question? Is it possible to apply the @property workaround not to the outermost/parent SVG element (as you mentioned) but the one below it? I tried targeting it, but for some reason it doesn't work.

That's the point - You can't apply CSS gradients (and other properties like padding) to SVG (child) elements. The outermost SVG is also an HTML element (that's why it works). So no you can't apply CSS gradients to e.g nested SVG els.

As another workaround you may also use a <foreignObject> for the gradient fill. Frankly I'm not a huge fan of them as they can be quite inconsistent in cross-browser rendering. Maybe you could also do the gradients in HTML/CSS and instead place your vector elements inside instead of including everything in a parent SVG. If you can't achieve what you're trying to do you may add a new question describing what's not working by a more detailed example.

Thank you so much for all the suggestions. I'm gonna try to modify my SVG document so that the target SVG element becomes the parent one, so that I can use the @property workaround. If that doesn't work, I'm gonna look at <foreignObject>. If that doesn't work, I'm gonna post a new question with more details. Thank you for being patient.

To animate the radial gradient in your SVG you need to ensure that the properties being animated are compatible with CSS animations. In SVG you cannot directly animate the offset property of gradient stops using CSS. Instead, you need to use SMIL (Synchronized Multimedia Integration Language) for animating $VG properties.
Here's how you can modify your SVG to animate the radial gradient using SMIL:


<svg id="svgDoc" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 500 500" shape-rendering="geometricPrecision" text-rendering="geometricPrecision">

<defs>
  <radialGradient id="svgGrad-fill" cx="50%" cy="50%" r="50%" spreadMethod="pad" gradientUnits="objectBoundingBox">
    <stop id="svgGrad-fill-0" offset="0%" stop-color="#ff0000">
      <animate attributeName="offset" from="0%" to="10%" dur="3s" begin="svgDoc:hover" repeatCount="indefinite" />
    </stop>
    <stop id="svgGrad-fill-1" offset="10%" stop-color="#000">
      <animate attributeName="offset" from="10%" to="100%" dur="3s" begin="svgDoc:hover" repeatCount="indefinite" />
    </stop>
  </radialGradient>
</defs>

<rect id="svgGrad" width="500" height="500" rx="0" ry="0" fill="url(#svgGrad-fill)"/>
</svg>




Sorry, this code is not working.
