# How to eliminate animation flicker on button using css?

Tags: html, css

I created buttons that have a hover effect. The button fills from bottom to top with a background color white, and the text changes color. However, there is this weird line that appears at the bottom when the animation takes place. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```css
.project-button div {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 1rem;
    margin: 0 1rem 1rem 1rem;
    
    font-size: 1rem;
    font-weight: 700;
    border: 1px solid white;
    border-radius: 15px;
    
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    transition: background-size .5s, color .5s;
}

.to-top {
    background-position: 50% 100%;
    background-size: 100% 0%;
}

.project-button a {
    color: white;
}

.project-button div:hover {
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-image: linear-gradient(white, white);
}

.color-blue:hover {
    color: #51d0de;
}

/* Misc */
html {
  background: black;
  margin: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div class="project-button">
    <a href="###"><div class="to-top color-blue">Visit Site</div></a>
</div>
```

Comment: should `className` not be `class`?

Comment: I'm using React. Forgot to mention that in the original comment.

Comment: No flicker when running this as plain HTML/CSS. Do you have live link?

Comment: No flicker on the above code snippet either (using Firefox)

Comment: I am on chrome and I can run the code snippet above through stack overflow and see a black line at the bottom of the interior of the button while the animation takes place

Comment: Same here on Chrome. Investigating.

Comment: Nothing like that for me, on google chrome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

I think the problem has to do with how Chrome computes the animation. At times (depending on the frame) the white background is just a bit too small to fill the button revealing the black background (hence the flicker).

```css
.project-button div {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 1rem;
  margin: 0 1rem 1rem 1rem;

  font-size: 1rem;
  font-weight: 700;
  border: 1px solid white;
  border-radius: 15px;

  background-image: linear-gradient(white, white);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 0 -100%;
  background-size: 100% 200%;
  transition: background-position .5s, color .5s;
}

.project-button a {
  color: white;
}

.project-button div:hover {
  background-position: 0% 0%;
}

.color-blue:hover {
  color: #51d0de;
}

/* Misc */
html {
  background: black;
  margin: 1em;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="project-button">
      <a href="###"><div class="color-blue">Visit Site</div></a>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Inspired by [Transition background-color via slide up animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20751937/transition-background-color-via-slide-up-animation)

Comment: Awesome! I still cannot figure out what you did that was different from my code by that cleared the issue right up! Thank you!

Comment: Always a pleasure!