# How to make div background slide in?

Tags: html, css, css-transitions, css-animations

I'd like to make a div's (just containing text) background slide in from left to right, how can i accomplish this? 
I can make it fade in using css transition but cannot figure out how to make it slide in.

```css
.container{
  display:inline;
  padding:10px;
  transition: background-color 2s;
}

.container:hover{
  background-color:lightcoral;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
    some text here
</div>
```

Comment: You need to use a `:before` or an `:after`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20751937/transition-background-color-via-slide-up-animation or this

Answer (score -1):

```
<style>
  div {
    height: 40px;
    width: 70%;
    background: black;
    margin: 50px auto;
    border-radius: 5px;
    position: relative;
  }

  #rect {
    animation-name: slide;
    animation-duration: 4s;
  }

  @keyframes slide {
    0% {
      left: 0px;
    }
    50% {
      left: 50px;
    }
    100% {
      left: 50px;

    }
  }
</style>

<div id="rect"></div>
```

You can try using a keyframes animation like this one. Adapted from: https://www.freecodecamp.org/learn/responsive-web-design/applied-visual-design/create-movement-using-css-animation

Comment: using id prevent you from using that animation more than once, not a big deal but not the best way to go. Also, it's not the background that is sliding but the whole element. And finally, remove the 50% if it's the same as 100%; that way it will be easier to configure your animation time (here your animation time is 4s/2)